# Suggestions for improving my method for finding the max value

Tags: python, optimization

I have a set called ISET; with a long list of 3-letter elements like: USA, BRA, CHN, ....

I also have a dictionary called heights. The keys for this dictionary are the elements of SET combined with a certain YEAR string. For example: USA1991, USA1992, ..., BRA1991, ... ...

What is the best way of finding the max height-value across all countries for a given year?

This is what I have been using:

```
YEAR = getuserselection()
for i in ISET:
    z = heights.get(i + YEAR, None)
    if z is None: continue
    if z > Max: Max = z
```

Any suggestions for improving it?

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you stick to a more common naming convention (that is to say, [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: Are you having problems with the amount of time this takes to execute?

Comment: @tkerwin: yes. I am. it executes every time the user slides a certain year-slider. Any improvements to it would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion, not actually measured: use a mapping `heights_per_year` from years to `dict`s mapping country codes to heights.

```
year = getuserselection()
heights = heights_per_year[int(year)]
max_height = max(a.itervalues())
```

Note the conversion to `int` for some extra speed (no need to compare strings).

Better yet, let `height_per_year` map to descending sorted `list`s of (country code, height) pairs.

```
max_height = heights[0][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `height` doesn't change much, cache the statistics you need, when you create or update the data.

Comment: +1: Because caching is a powerful technique and here is very simple to implement (`max_value[YEAR]`). Of course may be it can't be used in this specific case... the problem terms were too general to give any sure advice.

Answer (score 1):

What is just a rewording of your algorithm could be:

```
YRNormalizer = max(heights.get(z+YEAR, -99999) for z in ISET)
```

If you can you should have python doing the loops itself...

Comment: Or `float('-inf)` if you want to be *really* sure.

Comment: Or `None`, which is smaller than any number by `<`.

Comment: @larsmans: Where did you read that? I knew that comparison between different types are ordered consistently but arbitrarily (see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html ). Where is it stated that None is guaranteed to be less than anything else?

Comment: I determined that by experimentation. I'll admit it's not clean. Does arbitrarily mean something like UD in C?

Comment: @larsmans: it think that what the doc says simply means that if you find that a string is "less than" an int then at least until you exit the python program any string will be "less than" any int. By actually checking the source code of CPython 2.7.1 at least for that implementation it's true that None is smaller than anything unless specified explicitly because the C code makes it so (see. object.c line 775). You can of course make something still smaller than None by defining a proper `__lt__` operator.